# Android build suddenly locked to 30 fps from previous 60 fps

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So i was messing with particle simulation and doing quite many builds, when realized that the default target frame rate switched to 30 fps from 60 fps on my android phone. I started to analyze the changes i made but none affected parts that could change the default frame rate behavior. Then i realized i made a development build and attached a profiler previously.

- Could this have affected my device somehow?
- Can my android device decide on some factors when to run the game on 30hz even tho it could safely run it on 60hz?
  I really want to understand the behavior change.

**Unity 2019.4.2f1**
**ASUS_X00TD - Android 8.1.0**

(I know how to fix the problem but i want to understand the random behavior change)

Comment: Someone had similar problems like you, here you can find solution [Android FPS Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031279/unity-mobile-device-30fps-locked/47031517)

Comment: Thanks but as i said i'm not looking for a solution but for an explanation