# Unity - Android app fps: how to set them to 60?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

To be sure this is NOT a performance issue I started a new Unity Android game project containing nothing.

The simulation in the Unity editor run very smooth (no surprise) but when I build and test my new game on my Android device (S10), I get an FPS counter of 30 FPS.

I've tried literally everything listed here:
[Unity mobile device 30fps locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031279/unity-mobile-device-30fps-locked)

- turning off **optimizedFramePacing**
- disabled everything in my Adaptive **Performance Samsung Android package**
- added the `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;`instruction
- checked I have no other Application.targetFrameRate set elsewhere (easy check: project is EMPTY)
- turned off **vsync**

Still, my game runs at 30 fps.

In the single empty script I the tried:

```
void Update()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
}
```

and... it works! Now my games runs smooth at exactly 60 FPS on my mobile device.

The problem I have with this solution is I don't like the fact that every frame runs the instruction `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;`

I tried to set the targetFrameRate on for a short period of time, like this:

```
private int counter = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (counter < 150) {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and after 150, tha game still runs at 60FPS.
At the moment my code is more like this:

```
private bool flag = true;

void Update()
{
    if (flag ) {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

It seems I need just a single frame where I update the Application.targetFrameRate parameter and then it keeps running at 60FPS. Calling `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;` in start() or Awake() does not work.

Does anyone have any idea (not listed here: [Unity mobile device 30fps locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031279/unity-mobile-device-30fps-locked), ofc)?

Thank you, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you turn off vsync